# using Accordion from jQuery UI, I'm getting an unwanted blue highlight around the last clicked link

Tags: jquery-ui

I'm using the Accordion widget from jQuery UI.

Whenever I click a header to expand a section, that header (actually, the link *inside* the h3 element) is highlighted. In Chrome it has a blue highlight as if it were the currently selected  field in a form.

I need to get rid of the blue highlight, so I hacked together the code below, and it seems to work so far.

However, I'm wondering if there's a better/cleaner way to do this in jQuery. Is this right??

```
$(function() {
  $( "#mainnav" ).accordion().blur($('#mainnav'));
});
```

Comment: This also applies to other UI elements, it's like a blue focus rectangle in my case. Your answer below solved it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I didn't need jQuery to fix the problem after all (`.blur()` didn't seem to work).

jQuery was adding a `class = "ui-state-focus"` to the html, so I used CSS to indicate that this class shouldn't be outlined/highlighted, like so...

```
#mainnav .ui-state-focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For me works this for JQuery UI 1.9.2, Tabs widget:

```
#mainnav .ui-tabs-anchor {
  outline: none;
}
```